# Change Onclick Button Event to Page Onload Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

i have onclick button script alert, which is the alert displayed when i click the button. i need to modify the script, so the alert displayed when i load the page.

Button code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success swalDefaultSuccess">
                  Launch Success Toast
</button>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
      toast: true,
      position: 'top-end',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 3000
    });

    $('.swalDefaultSuccess').click(function() {
      Toast.fire({
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.'
      })
    });


</script>
```

anyone can help? 
thanks

Comment: Is this what you want to do? $(function() {
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({ ... });
    Toast.fire({ type: 'success', title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor s.'});
}

Comment: @Marc hello, thx for your response. u can check this sir. https://ibb.co/2SsR4H6 , top code is mw new code (my old code is on click event, i want to modified the code to onload script) but my script not working. can you help me?

Comment: Can you create a http://codepen.io  for us?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get the page load event.

**Explanation:**
These examples below will register an event that will listen to document/window loads. They must be specified somewhere(preferred inside ) in page source.

This will show an alert when page loads document and related contents(images, etc)

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(window).on('load', function(){
    Toast.fire({
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.'
    })
});
});
</script>
```

Document ready will run after document is ready.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
        Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.'
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Vanilla Js

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Toast.fire({
    type: 'success',
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.'
  })
});
</script>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        alert("DOM loaded");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Alert on page Loading</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you your answer..  can you teach me how to i attach this onload function to <body> or html ?  because before this onload i use onclick to a button : <button type="button" class="btn btn-success swalDefaultSuccess">

Comment: Just put it inside a script tag before the body, inside <head> is fine. Just updated the answer with script tag to be more clear

Comment: sir, thank you before.. but can you check this  ? https://ibb.co/2SsR4H6

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that you need to wrap jQuery functions inside jQuery wrapper. Can you try again with my updated answer? Looking your source code I certain that is it.